# PHP Connect to MySQL Database in Other Server

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 shared hostings: 1.1.1.1 and 2.2.2.2
I have a PHP script in 1.1.1.1 that connect to a database in 2.2.2.2
In Remote Database Access Hosts (2.2.2.2) I put '%' means that I allow connection from any IP
Database username in 2.2.2.2: foo
Database password in 2.2.2.2: bar

My PHP script:

```
mysql_connect('2.2.2.2:3306', 'foo', 'bar', true);
```

I got this error:

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Can't connect to MySQL server on '2.2.2.2' (4)
```

Comment: are these server connected? do you tested ping from each?

Comment: its not the issue but you should be using mysqli or pdo, mysql is deprecated

Comment: also, when you created your user on the remote host, was it created at localhost? If so you wont be able to log in even if you use%

Comment: @Akam: I don't know how to ping from each

Comment: @shankshera, open up the console/terminal/command prompt, and type `ping 2.2.2.2`.

Comment: @Drewdin: How to create user not at localhost? I use cPanel

Comment: @Prisoner: I don't know how to open up console in cPanel but both servers are accessible from here, I assume that they are connected.

Comment: If you have shared accounts, then most likely your web host doesn't allow you to access MySQL remotely. If you need this, contact them but they will most likely not enable it for you.

Comment: I think the new versions of cPanel have the ability to enable remote connection to your database without even calling the support. Just look into your Databases category in cPanel and use Remote MySQL.

Comment: whos your hosting company?

Answer (score 0):

If Your servers connected, make sure that on server 2.2.2.2 "my.cnf" mysql configuration file allows remote connections. [This](http://wiki.r1soft.com/display/CDP3/Allowing+Remote+Connections+to+MySQL+Instance) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. It's about firewall, I contact my hosting and they fixed it for me.